# QGIS v/s MapInfo - Differences in Distance Measurements

Tags: distance, qgis-processing, mapinfo, measurements, differences

Distance calculated in different software (MapInfo and QGIS) has given me differences in distance values. To be more precise, it's mostly happening when the distance is more than 25 miles. I doubt this is because QGIS is always including the earth curve (3D) while calculating distances, while in MapInfo, it's directly measuring the distances in 2D form.
Why I am sure about 3D and 2D impact is because the distance I am getting is always huge in QGIS when compared.

If this is the case, how can we calculate the distances in MapInfo with the earth curve included in measurements and should come similar to QGIS?

Comment: can you gives some examples of the two distances? is one in miles and the other in metres?

Comment: No. Both are in miles only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS does not always compute ellipsoidal areas. User can select planimetric areas with the project settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As suggested above, I have got the right answer just by switching to other options.

Answer (score 1):

In MapInfo Pro:
Be aware of Spherical or Cartesian calculus (see "map options" dialog). Check if your tool calculates ObjectLen () or CartesianObjectLen() or SphericalObjectLen() and if it matches your map option calculus mode.

Some more info here:
https://groups.google.com/g/mapinfo-l/c/ZQum8S9d4oU/m/quO8sDq6JW8J

Comment: The Documentation mentioned on MapInfo-L that Ross refers to, can now be found here: https://support.precisely.com/products/mapinfo-pro/